# How can we write ranges of data in multiple csv files, and the data should be fetched from dictionary

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary and I need to store dictionary key and value pair in the CSV file but I want only some specific ranges in the CSV file, for example, one CSV file contains only 10 number of rows.

for example, I have the following dictionary:

```
 data_dict = {"Jhon":[(75,25),(34,20),(33,88),(44,90),(43,99)],"Ram":[(10,11),(90,90),(11,34),(09,12),(-43,-99)]}
```

In this dictionary, in this sample CSV, I have two key and I want to store all element(key and value) of this dictionary

I need to generate CSV files from this data_dict. each CSV file should contain a specific number of data lines.

## Output file contains multiple CSV file each file contains only 10 rows.

output_csv_file_01.csv

```
     Name   Final_marks Practical_marks extra_marks
     Jhon   74          25              0
     Jhon   34          20              0
     Jhon   33          88              0
     Jhon   44          90              0
     Jhon   43          99              0
     Ram    10          11              0
     Ram    90          90              0
     Ram    11          34              0
     Ram    9           12              0
     Ram    -43        -99              0
```

output_csv_file02.csv

```
     Name   Final_marks Practical_marks  extra_marks
     Ram    88          76               0
     Ram    44          80               0
```

please check my code:

```
  import csv
  data_dict = {"Jhon":[(75,25),(34,20),(33,88),(44,90),(43,99)],"Ram":[(10,11),(90,90),(11,34),(09,12),(-43,-99)]}

  fields = ['Name','Final_marks', 'Practical_marks',extra_marks]
  file_name = 'output_csv_file_'
  file_number, rows_per_file = 1, 10

  for key,values in data_dict.items():
     for i in range(0, len(values), rows_per_file):
        with open(f'{file_name}{file_number}.csv', 'w', newline='') as fp:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(fp, fieldnames=fields)
        writer.writeheader()
        for row in values[i: i + rows_per_file]:
            writer.writerow({"Name":key,"Final_marks":row[0],"Practical_marks":row[1],"extra_marks":0})
        file_number += 1
```

Comment: And is something not working?

Comment: What is the output of your code? What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you have some number of keys and multiple 2-tuples per key, but only want one key and 2-tuple per row, and a max number of rows per file.

A generator can be used to return one key,2-tuple at a time across the data set, and the following code will only write a certain number of rows per file:

```py
import csv
data_dict = {"Jhon":[(75,25),(34,20),(33,88),(44,90),(43,99)],"Ram":[(10,11),(90,90),(11,34),(9,12),(-43,-99),(1,2)]}

header = ['Name','Final_marks', 'Practical_marks']
file_name = 'output_csv_file_'
file_number, rows_per_file = 1, 10

def fetch(data):
    for key,values in data.items():
        for value in values:
            yield (key,) + value   # e.g. ('John', 75, 25)

gen = fetch(data_dict)  # create a generator over all the data

for row in gen:         # fetch a row, if one isn't available, stop

    # Since at least one row is available, start a new file.
    # Ensuring one row is available prevents a header-only file
    # when there is an exact multiple of rows_per_file data rows.

    # Open file, write the header and first row
    with open(f'{file_name}{file_number}.csv', 'w', newline='') as fp:
        writer = csv.writer(fp)
        writer.writerow(header)
        writer.writerow(row)

        try:  # try to write up to the max rows per file, but stop if you run out
            for i in range(rows_per_file - 1):
                writer.writerow(next(gen))
        except StopIteration:
            break

        file_number += 1
```

Comment: could you please provide main some details regarding if I want to add one extra column name as "extra_marks" and need to put value for all rows as 0, so How can I do this. I will also add in my question

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach using [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
import csv
import random

from itertools import islice


PREFIX = "output_csv_file_"
ROWS = 10

header = ("Name", "Final_marks", "Practical_marks", "extra_marks")
data = {
    "Jhon": [(75, 25), (34, 20), (33, 88), (44, 90), (43, 99)],
    "Ram": [(10, 11), (90, 90), (11, 34), (9, 12), (-43, -99), (1, 2)],
}


def rows(randomize=True):
    extra_mark = 0

    for name, marks in data.items():
        for mark in marks:

            if randomize:
                extra_mark = random.randint(0, 100)

            yield (name,) + mark + (extra_mark,)


def main():
    i = 1
    it = rows()
    chunk = tuple(islice(it, 0, ROWS))

    while chunk:
        with open(f"{PREFIX}{i}.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(header)
            writer.writerows(chunk)

        chunk = tuple(islice(it, 0, ROWS))
        i += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Update: Sat 20 Mar 10:11:04 GMT 2021**

```
--- test.py.bak 2021-03-20 10:07:00.950388437 +0000
+++ test.py 2021-03-20 10:07:50.147515855 +0000
@@ -1,22 +1,29 @@
 import csv
+import random
 
 from itertools import islice
 
 
 PREFIX = "output_csv_file_"
-ROWS = 5
+ROWS = 10
 
-header = ("Name", "Final_marks", "Practical_marks")
+header = ("Name", "Final_marks", "Practical_marks", "extra_marks")
 data = {
     "Jhon": [(75, 25), (34, 20), (33, 88), (44, 90), (43, 99)],
     "Ram": [(10, 11), (90, 90), (11, 34), (9, 12), (-43, -99), (1, 2)],
 }
 
 
-def rows():
+def rows(randomize=True):
+    extra_mark = 0
+
     for name, marks in data.items():
         for mark in marks:
-            yield (name,) + mark
+
+            if randomize:
+                extra_mark = random.randint(0, 100)
+
+            yield (name,) + mark + (extra_mark,)
 
 
 def main():
```

Comment: could you please provide main some details regarding if I want to add one extra column name as "extra_marks" and need to put value for all rows as 0, so How can I do this.

Comment: and can we store random marks in the "extra_marks" column in all the CSV file

Comment: @Shradha please see my update, you can use the `randomize` parameter to either add  random or 0 marks.

Comment: Thank you, so after this main(): other codes are same correct

Comment: The top one is a fully working example and below is just a diff between the old and new version.